# Game animation from other video file into blender animation (adding to the existing video file)

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

I made tablet model in Blender. I also made animation where object is moving but I want to add some game animation (from other video file) on tablet display but I don't know how. If you have any link with tutorial where it is shown please send me it.

I want obtain such an effect [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B57lZfx5byWacm5kUlZYb0ItUFk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by assigning to your tablet model "screen" surface (probably a rectangle) a "image or movie" texture (obviously choosing your movie). Of course you need to learn how to correctly assign the texture to your mesh. You could do this either by UV mapping or using a separate material for the "screen" surface...

To add the video *after* the tablet animation is done, you can use video tracking to map your video to the screen area, but you will need to have  some good tracking feature in the animated screen, to get a good result (you need to be able to set good markers)

Comment: There is no other option? I have rendered animation and I don't want to render it one more time, just add extra video to file connected with display's material.

Comment: I suppose the video shown in the screen needs to follow the tablet, and so be animated, too... I feel you can't avoid that, unfortunately. no wait, you're right, I edit my answer.